# How to avoid nested loop in the trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, loop, nested

We have a trigger if case status got change new support record should get created.
but in my case it is creating more than one record, I am thinking it might be because of a nested loop can someone please suggest me how I can optimize

```
for(Support_Settings__c SS : allRecordTypeMap.values()){
    for(Case c1:trigger.new){
        if(SS.RecordTypeId__c == c1.RecordTypeId){}
```

support setting is a custom setting where I config red all record type, case status, recordtype id

Comment: why do you want to avoid nested loop?

Answer (score 3):

let's assume, you have only one `Support_Settings__c` record per each `Case` `RecordTypeId` field value. In this case,  in order to avoid nested loops, you can group `Support_Settings__c` records by `RecordTypeId__c` field. After that on iterating `Case` records in the trigger, just get value from `Map` by `Case` `RecortdTypeId` field value.

```
//grouping support settings by its RecordTypeId__c
Map<Id, Support_Settings__c> supportSettingsByRecordTypeIdMap = new Map<Id, Support_Settings__c>();
for(Support_Settings__c setting :allRecordTypeMap.values()){
    supportSettingsByRecordTypeIdMap.put(setting.RecordTypeId__c, setting);
}

for(Case c1 :trigger.new){
    if(supportSettingsByRecordTypeIdMap.containsKey(c1.RecordTypeId)){
        Support_Settings__c setting = supportSettingsByRecordTypeIdMap.get(c1.RecordTypeId);
        //do your actions here
    }
}
```